# Добавление логов в проект(включая логи EF)

Tags: c#, .net, логирование

проблема такая, добавил nLogger в проект, логи идут в Grafana, однако каждый лог описывать в контроллере не хочется, + к тому же нужно сделать так чтобы логи которые появляются в консоли(Связанные с базой данных) тоже шли в Grafan, как это реализуется?(Глобальное логирование?)
Сложность в том что проект с многослойной архитектурой, сервисы, абстракции и тд лежат в отдельных проектах,

```
[HttpPost]
[SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Получить весь список контента(Аватарки, файлы и т.д)")]
public async Task<IActionResult> All()
{
    var serviceName = nameof(_mediaService); // Получите имя сервиса
    _logger.LogInformation("Сработал метод получения контента для сервиса {0}", serviceName);

    var result = await _mediaService.GetAll();

    var mapResult = _mapper.Map<List<MediaModelResponse>>(result);

    _logger.LogInformation("JSON-тело: {0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mapResult)); // Отправьте JSON-тело в логи

    return Ok(mapResult);
}
```

пока что получилось только возвращать в логах тело json через добавление логгера в конкретный контроллер

Сам проект выглядит так
[image: Как выглядит проект]

Comment: У ASP из коробки есть [отличнейший инструмент](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging), который решает все, кастомизируется как надо, и внедряется куда надо. Вот допустим стандартный сайт ASP.NET с авторизацией (также из коробки), проект создан студией, и я уже имею **везде** [логгирование](https://i.stack.imgur.com/easas.png), включая веб запросов и прочих приблуд, ну а если мне нужно использовать логгирование где либо, то просто внедряю `ILogger` и все. Может стоит посмотреть всеж в сторону "коробки" и подключить туда все, что вам надо?

Comment: обычно это работает так: в вашем апи проекте вы настраиваете единое логирование на все приложение через DI, т.е. напрямую nlogger вы не используете, а пользуетесь ILogger, при этом все зависимости EF, контроллеры, ... используют эти интерфейсы зарегистрированные в DI, поэтому логи всегда выводятся в одинаковом формате в консоль, а потом их что-то собирает и отправляет в другие сервисы, в вашем случае grafana.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten просто совсем недавно занимаюсь программированием, именно с реализацией проблемы, примеры кода ищу

Comment: @EvgeniyZ примеры кода хотелось бы, так как не понимаю как это реализовать, как сделать так чтобы стандартный логгер работал с Grafana?

Comment: Я вам скинул документацию, где ведь все доходчиво написано. Вам нужно реализовать [пользовательского поставщика](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider) и зарегистрировать его в контейнере, после чего логи будут отправляться туда, куда вам надо. Если лень это делать самостоятельно, то используйте уже [готовые инструменты](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#third-party-logging-providers), например, Serilog, который отлично внедряется в стандартный логгер и имеет допустим пакет `Serilog.Sinks.Grafana.Loki`.